# Access VBA - add new column to existing table with name of the actual table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have imported various tables - WIP_100_AGR_USERS, WIP_100_USR06, WBP_100_USR02 with their real names as they were downloaded from SAP. Now I would need to add column "SYSTEM_NO"where would be the name of the table by use of VBA for ACCESS next to all other records in the particular table.

E.g. I have table WIP_100_USR06, so the result will be:

```
AGR NAME| SYSTEM NO
________|______________
ashkjas | WIP_100_USR_06
asdjhjh | WIP_100_USR_06
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing none of your tables already have a field named `SYSTEM NO` then this should work:

```
Sub InsertNameField()

    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "MSys" And Left(tdf.Name, 1) <> "~" Then
            CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE [" & tdf.Name & _
                "] ADD COLUMN [SYSTEM NO] TEXT(255)", dbFailOnError

            CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [" & tdf.Name & _
                "] SET [SYSTEM NO] = '" & tdf.Name & "'", dbFailOnError

        End If
    Next tdf

    MsgBox "Finished."

End Sub
```

**NB** Test on a copy of your database first.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! Works like a charm. Just one question to complicate it a bit :) How would it be possible to tdf.Name show only the text before the second underscore? Thus, WIP_100, please? I have tried the left  function, but length of system names varies by  length - e.g. PA_40, SGWC_1400 etc. Thank you!

Comment: They'll only have a maximum of two underscores (i.e. take everything before the last underscore)?

Comment: You'd use `LEFT(tdf.Name, INSTRREV(tdf.Name,"_")-1)`.  [INSTRREV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instrrev-function) returns the position of an occurrence of one string within another, from the end of the string.  So the `LEFT` function returns everything to the left of whatever number `INSTRREV` returns.

Comment: Splendid! Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually it should be everything before the second (the middle underscore), can I use the MID function, please? Thank you!

Comment: Because this way it leaves WIP_100_AGR from the name WIP_100_AGR_USERS. However I would need only WIP_100...so how would I get the text before second occurence of _ (underscore)? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, already solved it! Thank you very much! The string was "CurrentDb.Execute `UPDATE [" & tdf.Name & _
                "] SET [SYSTEM NO] = '" & Left(tdf.Name, InStr(InStr(1, tdf.Name, "_") + 1, tdf.Name, "_") - 1) & "'", dbFailOnError`